# CKEditor Upload images while the paste content contains <img /> tag

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor in React. I would like to implement a function: when I paste contents that was copied from other sources, if there are  tags, I want these images to be uploaded to server automatically. Maybe using some kind of event/listener? I am not sure. Can someone help me with this? Show me some code example if possible. Thanks!

```
<CKEditor
    editor={ ClassicEditor }
    data={content}
    config = {{ 
        toolbar: {
            items: [ 'heading', 'fontFamily', 'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', '|','link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'blockQuote', 'code', 'codeBlock', '|', 'imageUpload', 'mediaEmbed', '|', 'insertTable', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'sourceEditing'],
            shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
        }
    }}
                            

    onReady={(editor)=>
        {
            editor.plugins.get("FileRepository").createUploadAdapter = function(loader) {
                return new UploadAdapter(loader)
            };
        }
     }
     onChange = {(event, editor)=>{
     }}

     onBlur = {
         (event,editor)=>{
              let data = editor.getData()
              setContent({content: data})
          }
     }

/>
```

I was trying `editor.on('paste', function(){})` in OnReady, but looks like it doesn't work.